# Set space between columns, so each column is same size (using foundation)

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to make some space between my columns, but can't seem to find the right solution.

**Code:**

```
<div class="content wrapper">
<div class="row">
    <div class="red window border-right column small-12 medium-3">
        Section 1
    </div>
    <div class="green window border-left border-right column small-12 medium-3">
        Section 2
    </div>
    <div class="blue window border border-left border-right column small-12 medium-3">
        Section 3
    </div>
    <div class="yellow window border-left column small-12 medium-3">
        Section 4
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Have tried setting classes as border-right, border-left on the columns, but then, the left and right column will be bigger in size than the two in the middle (I'm using middle-3, so have 4 columns).

**Image:**

[image]

**Css:**

```
.window {
background-color: white;
height: 450px;
}

.window.border-left {
border-left: 8px solid #EAEDEE;
}

.window.border-right {
border-right: 8px solid #EAEDEE;
}

.yellow {
background-color: yellow;
padding: 1rem;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
padding: 1rem;
}

.blue {
background-color: cadetblue;
padding: 1rem;
}

.green {
background-color: green;
padding: 1rem;
}
```

Is this possible, without applying it global?

Answer (score 1):

please you can try this, i hope you need this.

CSS:

```
.content.wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.window {
background-color: white;
height: 450px;
}

.window.border-left {
border-left: 8px solid #EAEDEE;
}

.window.border-right {
border-right: 8px solid #EAEDEE;
}

.yellow {
background-color: yellow;
padding: 1rem;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
padding: 1rem;
}

.blue {
background-color: cadetblue;
padding: 1rem;
}

.green {
background-color: green;
padding: 1rem;
}  
.border-right, .border-left {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

See [Bootply Updeted Demo](http://www.bootply.com/qZKywLzsVx)

Comment: you can see that they are not equally big.

Answer (score 0):

Could please try this code

```
<div class="content wrapper">
    <div class="row" data-equalizer="">
        <div class="column small-12 medium-3">
            <div class="red window border-right" data-equalizer-watch="">Section 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-right column small-12 medium-3">
            <div class="green window border-left" data-equalizer-watch="">Section 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-left border-right column small-12 medium-3">
            <div class="blue window border" data-equalizer-watch="">Section 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column small-12 medium-3">
            <div class="yellow window border-left" data-equalizer-watch="">Section 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have modified only the HTML part. you can use the same css

Comment: @Mikkel My i know are using Foundation 5 or 6

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
```

`.row {
display:flex;
justify-content:space-between;
}`

```
`.row div {
flex:0 1 23%;
}`
```

be sure to use http://autoprefixer.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

try this...

in a include your head part this link.
this link is zurb foundation css.
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation-flex.css